# Join two tables to list all conversations of user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

I've four tables:

**chat** (users to users)

```
id | id_user_from | id_user_to
1  | 1            | 2
2  | 1            | 3
3  | 3            | 2
4  | 4            | 1
```

**message** (users to users)

```
id | content | date                | id_chat | id_user_from | id_user_to
1  | hi      | 2017-10-04 23:14:41 | 1       | 1            | 2
2  | hello   | 2017-10-04 23:15:03 | 1       | 2            | 1
3  | heey    | 2017-10-04 23:40:00 | 3       | 3            | 2
4  | ops     | 2018-01-04 20:00:00 | 4       | 4            | 1
```

**page_chat** (users to pages / pages to user)

```
id | id_user | id_page
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 3
3  | 4       | 3
4  | 4       | 2
```

**page_message** (users to pages / pages to user)

```
id | content | date                | id_page_chat | id_user | id_page | from (0 = user; 1 = page)
1  | from pg | 2017-07-04 23:14:41 | 1            | 1       | 1       | 1
2  | from usr| 2018-10-04 23:15:03 | 2            | 1       | 3       | 0
3  | to usr  | 2018-10-04 23:40:00 | 2            | 1       | 3       | 1
4  | hi page | 2018-10-04 23:40:00 | 3            | 4       | 3       | 0
```

And I'm using the following code to get last message of each conversation:

**(users to users)** (`$userId` is the user logged id; `$idsChat` are `id_chat`'s that already loaded - using because of infinite scrolling):

```
select m1.*
from message m1
join
(
  SELECT MAX(id) as id
  FROM message
  WHERE $userId IN (id_user_from, id_user_to) AND id_chat NOT IN (".implode(",", $idsChat).")
  GROUP BY id_chat
  ORDER BY id DESC
) m2 on m1.id = m2.id
```

**(users to pages / pages to user)** (`$userId` is the user logged id; `$idsChat` are `id_page_chat`'s that already loaded - using because of infinite scrolling):

```
select m1.*
from page_message m1
join
(
  SELECT MAX(id) as id
  FROM page_message
  WHERE id_user = $userId AND id_page_chat NOT IN (".implode(",", $idsChat).")
  GROUP BY id_page_chat
  ORDER BY id DESC
) m2 on m1.id = m2.id
```

And they work perfectly. But now I want to join (I don't know if by PHP or SQL itself) these two queries, to display to user your conversations with users and pages together. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, you combine your messages into one query:

```
select `content`, `date`, id as m_id, id_chat, id_user_from, id_user_to,
  null as p_id, null as id_page_chat, null as id_user, null as id_page, null as `from`
from message
union all
select `content`, `date`, null as m_id, null as id_chat, null as id_user_from, null as id_user_to,
  id as p_id, id_page_chat, id_user, id_page, `from`
from page_message
```

Then you can use that as the base table for your query to look up the most recent message from each conversation. (This code would be much cleaner if you used the above query to create a *view*, and referenced that instead.)

```
select *
from (select `content`, `date`, id as m_id, id_chat, id_user_from, id_user_to,
      null as p_id, null as id_page_chat, null as id_user, null as id_page, null as `from`
    from message
    union all
    select `content`, `date`, null as m_id, null as id_chat, null as id_user_from, null as id_user_to,
      id as p_id, id_page_chat, id_user, id_page, `from`
    from page_message) m1
join
(select max(m_id) as m_id, max(p_id) as p_id
   from (select `content`, `date`, id as m_id, id_chat, id_user_from, id_user_to,
          null as p_id, null as id_page_chat, null as id_user, null as id_page, null as `from`
        from message
        union all
        select `content`, `date`, null as m_id, null as id_chat, null as id_user_from, null as id_user_to,
          id as p_id, id_page_chat, id_user, id_page, `from`
        from page_message) all_msgs
   where $userId IN (id_user_from, id_user_to, id_user) 
     AND IFNULL(id_chat, id_page_chat) NOT IN (".implode(",", $idsChat).")
   group by id_chat, id_page_chat
   order by m_id desc, p_id desc
) m2 on (m1.m_id = m2.m_id or m1.p_id = m2.p_id)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/455ea/16)

Comment: It working! I just added `ORDER BY BY date DESC` at the end of query to get the messages in order, and I used `(id_chat NOT IN (".implode(",", $idsChat).") or id_page_chat NOT IN (".implode(",", $idsPageChat).")` (that's in your fiddle) instead of  `IFNULL(id_chat, id_page_chat) NOT IN (".implode(",", $idsChat).")`, because the second one was "deleting" conversations (if loaded user/user conversation with `id_chat = 1`, it didn't load user/page conversation with `id_page_chat = 1` and vice versa)